# Return value ajax

Tags: javascript

```
function storeExportFG (dataStore) {
    var storeEx = $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: window.location.origin + '/export-fg-warehouse/store',
        cache: false,
        data: dataStore,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    return storeEx;
}
dataStore = {
    'id'    : table.row(point).data()[1],
    'number': table.row(point).data()[5],
};
storeExportFG(dataStore).done(function (data){});
storeExportFG(dataStore).fail(function (err){});
```

This is my code. The problem I encountered was when doing so, my code would be added to the database twice at the same time.
How can I print out error values?

Comment: You are calling the function every time you do `storeExportFG(dataStore)` which is twice. I guess, that's why the data is added twice. You should just call it once: `storeExportFG(dataStore).done(function (data){}).fail(function (err){})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach

```js
dataStore = {
    'id'    : table.row(point).data()[1],
    'number': table.row(point).data()[5]
};

function storeExportFG (dataStore) {
    var storeEx = $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: window.location.origin + '/export-fg-warehouse/store',
        cache: false,
        data: dataStore,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    return storeEx;
}

storeExportFG(dataStore).done(function (data){

}).fail(function (err){

});
```